# How should I access a Spring MVC rest service using javascript?

Tags: jquery, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a Spring-MVC based rest service returning json which is setup like so

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class JSONController {

@Autowired
private FooService fooService;

@RequestMapping(value = "{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<Foo> getFoos(@PathVariable String name)
```

I plan on doing the rest of the CRUD operations through this api - what I was wondering was how should I write a client - using Json or JsonP?

At the moment I've retrieved the list of Foos with

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "http://xxx.com/rest/api/1",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        $.each(data, function(index, data) {

            var foo = $.extend(new Foo(result[key].name));
            users.push(foo );

        });

    }
});
```

I can see the returned objects in firebug but the success callback is not reached. Is there a proper client side pattern for interacting with restful services?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your call is not reaching the success function because you are returning the list of you call in jsonp format. The mapper i think JacksonMapper is returning the list in "json" format.

If you use:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://xxx.com/rest/api/1",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        $.each(data, function(index, data) {

            var foo = $.extend(new Foo(result[key].name));
            users.push(foo );

        });

    }
});
```

It should work, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found the answer I needed in a few blogs by adding CORS support to the backend request. Here's some more info http://java-success.blogspot.com.au/2012/11/jsonp-and-jquery-with-spring-mvc.html